# c embedded: static struct initialization with defined struct variable name

Tags: c, struct, static, embedded

Creating this struct:

```
typedef enum {

  IDLE = 0,

  SENT  = 1,

  RECEPTION     = 2,

  DONE          = 3,

  ABORT               = 4,

} State_t;



typedef struct {

    State_t state;

    u8 N;

    u8 last;

    u16 time;

}__attribute__((packed)) Context_t;
```

Want to initialize it with struct variable names. This gives me an error:

```
static Context_t arr[MAX_CONTEXT] = {
    
            .state = IDLE, .N= 1, .last= 0, .time= 0
    
        };
```

as well as this:

```
  static Context_t arr[MAX_CONTEXT];

    arr = {

        .state = IDLE, .N= 1, .last= 0, .time= 0

    };
```

This of course work, but is not what i want:

```
static Context_t arr[MAX_CONTEXT] = {
    
            IDLE, 1,  0, 0
    
        };
```

Does anybody have a better way of implementing this struct?

Comment: It is an array for which you only provide one initializer. All other elements are set to 0. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get errors because it usually doesn't make sense to initialize *an array of struct* with a single struct item's initializers.

If your intention is to only initialize the first item in the array, then it should be:

```
static Context_t arr [MAX_CONTEXT] = 
{
  { .state = IDLE, .N= 1, .last= 0, .time= 0 },
};
```

or if you will: `[0] = { .state = IDLE, .N= 1, .last= 0, .time= 0 },`

Comment: Was trying to initialize all terms to the same default values. See now that I have to do this one bye one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the compiler but try this one out maybe:

```
    static Context_t arr[MAX_CONTEXT] = {
        {.state=IDLE, .N=1, .last=0, .time=0}, // 0
        {.state=IDLE, .N=1, .last=0, .time=0}, // 1
        ...
        {.state=IDLE, .N=1, .last=0, .time=0}  // MAX_CONTENT
    };
```

Comment: Yes this works, but was hoping for a way to set all values in array to the same, but thank you for the contribution